# Replacing # and #NUM! with Blank in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am having a bit difficult understanding how to display blank instead of the `#` and `#NUM!` in my report text box. Below is my statement and I did check other post about this issue but I haven't been able to figure it out. Please advise.

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Sum(Fields!Task_Count.Value)) = True
     ,0
     ,Sum(Fields!Task_Count.Value))/Sum(Fields!Visit_Count.Value)
```

Comment: have you tried using "" instead of 0 ?

Comment: @briskovich  I ended up doing this and it somewhat worked but it only removed the #NUM! so i still have the # reflected.

=iif(isnothing(Sum(Fields!Task_Count.Value)) = true, 0, sum(Fields!Task_Count.Value))/iif(isnothing(sum(Fields!Visit_Count.Value)) = true, 0, sum(Fields!Visit_Count.Value))